What statistical test can I use to compare binary variant calls between two non-independent samples for the same set of genes?
I have data from two biological samples, a control and a subject, where I'm tracking the presence or absence of genetic variants across a shared set of genes. Each row in the dataset represents a gene, and each column represents a binary outcome (True/False) indicating whether a variant is present in that sample for that gene. The data format looks like this:



Gene
Control
Subject




Gene1
True
True


Gene2
False
False


Gene3
True
False


Gene4
True
True


...
...
...



My goal is to determine if the pattern of variants between the control and subject samples is the same across this set of genes. In other words, I want to test whether the two samples show a similar profile of variant presence or absence.
A few considerations:

The two samples (control and subject) are biologically related: the subject was derived from the control but was grown in a different environmental or cultural condition.
The genes in this set are not necessarily independent of one another; there may be correlations between variants across genes due to biological factors, pathways, or other underlying structures.

What statistical test would be appropriate to determine if the variant patterns are similar between the control and subject samples, given these constraints?
Any guidance on how to handle this scenario, or advice on specific tests or models that account for the non-independence between genes/samples, would be greatly appreciated!
